# How to make a new nested list from an old nested list by merging all the elements at the same index together

Tags: python-3.7

I have a dictionary of key-value pairs. My value is a nested list. I am trying to make a new nested list out of the old one by combining all the elements with same index together.

I have tried making a new list of the old one,so that it doesn't change my original dictionary. I tired using a loop and indexing my values but it doesn't give me what i need

```
dict_mutated = []
for key,value,i in dict_ni.items():
     dict_mutated['lst_{}'.format(i)] = [item[i] for item in value]
```

I get an error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

```
 My input looks like
    {lst_0_0 :[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d' ,'e' ,'f'],['g' ,'h' ,'i']],
     lst_0_1 :[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],['d1' ,'e1' ,'f1'],['g1' ,'h1' ,'i1']]} 

I expect to get 
    {lst_0_0: [['a' 'd' 'g'], ['b' 'e' 'h'], ['c' 'f' 'i']],
     lst_0_1: [['a1' 'd1' 'g1'], ['b1' 'e1' 'h1'], ['c1' 'f1' 'i1']]
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
data = {"lst_0_0" :[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d' ,'e' ,'f'],['g' ,'h' ,'i']],
     "lst_0_1" :[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],['d1' ,'e1' ,'f1'],['g1' ,'h1' ,'i1']]} 

result = {}

for k, v in data.items():
    result[k] = [list(i) for i in zip(*v)]
print(result)
```

---

Or a `dict` comprehension.

```
result = {k: [list(i) for i in zip(*v)] for k, v in data.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{'lst_0_0': [['a', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'i']],
 'lst_0_1': [['a1', 'd1', 'g1'], ['b1', 'e1', 'h1'], ['c1', 'f1', 'i1']]}
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. This is exactly what i needed. Could i please ask if *v means for all the values ?

Comment: `*v` is to unpack the element in the list.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh for your time and help.